# Question on syzygies

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, exact-sequence

It is hard to formulate a question, but I want to ask about a reference/recipe for computing syzygies in general.

For example, on $\mathbb{P}^1_{(x:y)}$ there is an exact sequence

$0\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-3)^2\xrightarrow{\quad A\quad} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^!}(-2)^3\xrightarrow{\quad (x^2,xy,y^2)\quad} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\longrightarrow0$

I was told 
$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    y & 0 \\
    -x & y \\
    0 & -x
\end{bmatrix}$.

Is there a theory that helps determine $A$? How can a person see this so easily? What is the intuition behind such a choice of $A$?

(I could write out the matrix and compute its entries without too much difficulty, but there must be a systematic theory?)

Comment: There **is** a systematic theory for doing these kind of computations and that is the theory of *Gröbner bases*. In general however, the algorithms are too complex to be done by hand. Computer algebra systems such as Macaulay2 do them for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the points are distinct -- i.e., do not coïncide -- AND the determinant of their coördinates vanishes, you have a syzygy. Is that what you are seeking?